# Horizontal scroll bar showing on top of top menu

Tags: bug, horizontal-scroll-bar

[image: Horizontal scroll bar visible above top menu.]

Saw this while muddling around. I'd interacted with the horizontal scroll bar on a code snippet that's just covered by the top menu, and when I scrolled down to that the horizontal scroll appeared on top of the top menu.

**Notes**:

- I'm using macOS Sierra and Chrome.
- The trick is having the scroll bar persist long enough to see the effect; the screenshotted time had the scroll bar staying visible even without my action, which made this most noticeable

Comment: What kind of device are you using and which browser because I can't repro on Windows 10/Chrome. For reference, this is the question in the screnshot:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-is-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings

Comment: macOS Sierra and Chrome. The trick is having the scroll bar persist long enough to see the effect; the screenshotted time had the scroll bar staying visible even without my action, which made this most noticeable.

Comment: Can you repro that on any question with code blocks or does it only happen on that particular question? I mean, the unicode weirdness going on in that question could be the root cause.

Comment: Tried it and saw it again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262403/find-where-object-is-retained-with-arc

Comment: Seems to be vertical scroll bars too.

Comment: You are on 100% zoom? And does it also happen if you disable the stickyness of the header in your profile settings?

Comment: 100% zoom, yes. I don't see that setting anywhere.

Comment: I can repro, same OS/Chrome (but only with scrollbars set to only show when scrolling, doesn't happen if they're always visible)

Comment: see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343483/578411) for stickyness control.

Comment: If I disable the stickiness, this can't happen; the bug is caused by the header overlapping with the scroll bar, so it can't happen if the header doesn't scroll with the page.